# Selecting Column Name With Similar Pattern in a Loop

Tags: oracle, multiple-columns

I have an oracle database table with columns field_name_1, field_name_2,..., field_name_200.
I want to select and update each column in a loop for each row of data, kindly assist.

```
    DECLARE

    l_udf_vals  tablea%ROWTYPE;

    field_val_temp  varchar2(150);

    field_val   field_val_temp%TYPE;

    BEGIN
     FOR yu IN (SELECT a.*  FROM  tablea a, tableb b, tablec  c
                WHERE a.function_id=b.function_id AND b.col = c.col AND  )
      LOOP
      FOR i IN 1..200
       LOOP

        field_val_temp := 'field_val_'||i;

        SELECT field_val_temp INTO field_val FROM  tableb 
        WHERE  function_id='STDCUSAC' AND rec_key = yu.rec_key;

        IF field_val IS NOT NULL THEN
         UPDATE tablec  SET 'field_val_'||i = field_val;

       END LOOP;
       COMMIT;
      END LOOP; 
      COMMIT;
    END;
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting your questions here. It makes them harder to read, it won't get you answers any faster, and it's rather annoying. There are Shift keys on both sides of your keyboard to make it easier to use them. Please do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT '||field_val_temp ||' FROM  tableb 
    WHERE  function_id = :func_val AND rec_key = :rec_key' INTO field_val
  USING 'STDCUSAC' , yu.rec_key;
```

And,

```
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE tablec  SET field_val_'||i||' = :field_val'
  USING field_val;
```

You have to use [Dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm). But as @duffymo says, rethink to normalize the table. Also, if you update the same table, try to frame it as one single query string, for multiple columns after looping.

Comment: Thanks so much OracleUser for this idea. What I intend to achieve is to update tablea (having those 200 field_val_* columns ) with data from another table(tableb, having same structure as tablea) where ever corresponding column data in tableb is not null.  The code I posted may not have stated my intention very well. Please assist. Just coming up on PL/SQL. Thank you again.

Comment: Thanks so much once again. The Execute Immediate statements worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

This is a terrible idea on so many levels.

First of all, it's not normalized.

Second, you'll die a latent death.  The performance will be terrible.

This is not the way to save keystrokes.  I'd refactor the schema and the code.